# How to flip the rows of a list horizontally using slicing operator in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, matrix, 2d, slice

```
def matrixflip(myl,c):
   if(c=='v'):
       myl=myl[::-1]
       return myl
   elif(c=='h'):
       myl=myl[::][::-1]
       return myl
   else:
       return myl

myl=[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
print(matrixflip(myl,'h'))
```

## Expected output: [[2,1],[4,3]]

In the above code I'm calling the matrixflip() function to flip the rows of list/ flip the 2d matrix horizontally by passing the second argument as 'h'. However, i still get the vertically flipped version.

Comment: What do you expect `myl` to look like after it's flipped?

Comment: Expected output: [[2,1],[4,3]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse each sublist. The easiest way to do this is probably with a list comprehension expression:

```
result = [x[::-1] for x in myl]
```

Comment: But why though? Logically, it seems like OP's code should work.